# Could not find repository of robotium

Tags: java, android

I tried to automation testing using robotium android testing tool so that it can synchronise with my gradle file, and what is the repository of robotium.

```
Error:>Could not find com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo-5.5.3:
```

Comment: could you post your gradle file for reference?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to declare the dependency would be:

```
com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.5.3
```

Make sure you're using `jcenter()` as your repository.

Comment: I am using jcenter() as a repository.still same issue

Comment: Did you fix the dependency declaration? The one you mentioned in your question is incorrect, be careful with the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
compile group: 'com.jayway.android.robotium', name: 'robotium-solo', version: '5.6.3'
```

[Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.android.robotium/robotium-solo/5.6.3)